# Seal Script Title + Artist Seals

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

This is another part of the same book I posted on here yesterday - I'm certain I've got one of the characters, I'm unsure of another, and I'm really struggling with the last one. If anyone is able to read them it would be of immense help - contextually, it would make sense for it to be the title of an old Chinese poem.

I've gotten as far as (reading Right - Left) "X 厡(?) 圖"

[image: Title in Seal]

Also, if anyone is able to help with the seals in the below picture, that'd be great (they're a bit too artsy for me to read).

Thanks,
Thomas.

[image: Artist Seals]

Comment: 秋原圖 the first three characters

Comment: Thanks @TooskyHierot!

Comment: @TooskyHierot errrrrmmmm the first character is 桃. Second image, first two characters on the first seal are 明義 (both 明 and 義 uses variant shapes). Sorry, I only had time for a quick scan :)

Comment: @droooze oh you r right it is 桃原圖 sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> 桃原圖

As for the other two seals, I'm fairly sure that they're both referring to one person mentioned [on this page](http://www.ic.daito.ac.jp/%7Eoukodou/gallery/pic-1349.html):

[image]

> 明義父

[image]

> I won't presume the order that you're supposed to read this, so the characters in their positions are:
>
> 惇　　平
>
> 信＊　印
>
> ---
>
> ＊*Not sure of this character, looks like some sort of modification from*「言」.

Comment: Thanks @droooze! I was unsure of the reading for the seals, but they definitely make sense as belonging to 平林惇信 (I'd been using the same website you linked where they have blown-up versions of his seals, but for some bizarre reason they didn't include these two). The overall book this comes out of seems to be a collection of Tang dynasty poems, although I haven't been able to find any text for the one titled "桃原圖" (The other 3 poems are 把酒問月, 將進酒, and 西亭春望).

Comment: @TKNZ Multiple reasons why you can't find "桃原圖" as a poem: (1) 圖 refers to a picture or painting, so if a poem actually exists, 桃原圖 would only refer to a painting of a scene in the poem; (2) 原 is the original character for 源 (and 源 doesn't exist in Seal Script), so you have to search for a poem with the word 桃源 in the title. For example, there is a poem called 《桃源行》 written in the Tang Dynasty by 王維.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I had thought having the character 圖 was odd, as the title prefaces a long passage of text, and as far as I can tell no portion of the book that might have had an illustration has been excised or otherwise removed. Maybe it's a remnant of something that got lost in translation when the calligrapher copied from an original source. I guess I'll never know.